# \multirow command problem

Tags: tables, multirow

I need to vertical center the name of month on a table with 3 column.
I need to vertical center on the firs column, in the middle of the 2 or 3 lines. I don't understand the documentation of the package.

```
       %----------------------------------------------------
        \begin{tabular}{@{}llr@{}} 
            \toprule
           %\multirow{2}{*}{A}
            %\multirow{2}{4em}{marzo}\\ 
         16&ore 21.00&Bla bla bla\\
   \multirow{2}{0 em}{marzo}\\ 
            31 &ore 18.00&bla bla bla\\
     \cmidrule(r){1-2} %---- crea una linea fra le prime due colonne
            01 aprile&ore 10.00&bla bla bla\\
            20 &ore 21.00&bla bla bla\\
             \cmidrule(r){1-2}
            05 maggio&ore 18:00&bla bla bla\\
            06 &ore 10:00&bla bla bla\\
           \cmidrule(r){1-2}
            02 giugno&ore 21:00&bla bla bla\\
            03 & &\emph{bla bla bla}\\
            15 &ore 18:00&bla bla bla\\
\bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
%-------------------------------------------
```

Can someone give me an example?

Comment: Which table environment are you using?
What have you tried already? Maybe give some lines of what you have up untill now

Comment: without see example of your table (in form of complete but small document begining with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document} containing only necessary packages and your table, we cant help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this what you had in mind:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{booktabs,multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccccl}
\toprule
16 & \multirow{2}{*}{March}   & ore 21.00  &Bla bla bla\\
31 &                          & ore 18.00  &bla bla bla\\
\midrule
01 & \multirow{2}{*}{April} &ore 10.00 &bla bla bla\\
20 &                        &ore 21.00 &bla bla bla\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is what you want to achieve.

The `\multirow` command has this syntax:

```
\multirow{number_of_rows}{width}{contents}
```

If you put `*` for the width, the content's natural width is taken.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{@{}llll@{}} 
        \toprule
        \multirow{2}{*}{marzo} & 16 & ore 21.00 & Bla bla bla\\
                               & 31 & ore 18.00 & bla bla bla\\
        \cmidrule(r){1-3}
        \multirow{2}{*}{aprile} & 01 & ore 10.00 & bla bla bla\\
                                & 20 & ore 21.00 & bla bla bla\\
        \cmidrule(r){1-3}
        \multirow{2}{*}{maggio} & 05 & ore 18:00 & bla bla bla\\
                                & 06 & ore 10:00 & bla bla bla\\
        \cmidrule(r){1-3}
        \multirow{3}{*}{giugno} & 02 & ore 21:00 & bla bla bla\\
                                & 03 &           & \emph{bla bla bla}\\
                                & 15 & ore 18:00 & bla bla bla\\
        \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]